# Xcode - Get Image name or extension

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6

How to get the image name(or image extension format) of the image picked from UIImagePickerController of source type UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{
    NSURL *imagePath = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];
    NSString *imageName = [imagePath lastPathComponent];
}
```

Comment: I am getting it as asset.JPG for UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary but not for UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera, it says null.

Comment: I think it is not possible when you capture the image from the camera and you want to know the name of that image because the delegate gives you `UIImage` object as a parameter that you can save it to your album after that or what ever you want to do with that. Yes there is one solution that you can provide your own name to that image by creating a randomized string and save the image with that name.

Comment: Yes i can give my own name,but i need to give the correct extension also like png,jpg...

Comment: for that you first have to convert that `UIImage` to `NSData`. If you want to give an extension to the file as JPG then you have to convert `UIImage` to `NSData` using the function `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5)` and then save it to disk with the file name as "TestImage.jpg" and if you want to save it as PNG then you can convert it using `UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)` and save it with name as "TestImage.png"

Comment: so i can change the property(extension) of the image but i can't get the original property(extension)

Comment: Yes you can't because its just a `UIImage`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look below code

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[info[0] objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] pathExtension])//image extention
NSLog(@"%@",[[info[0] objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] pathComponents])//image name
```

Comment: Expected method to read array element not found on object of type 'NSDictionary *'